# Monogame/XNA, move sprite to mouseclick position

Tags: monogame

i wanna make a sprite move to the mouseclick (like in most strategie games). But i made it only while i press and hold the left mouse button so far. When i change the if-clauses to while loops, the sprite goes immediately to the mouse position.
Can someone help me? Is there maybe an easier way to make a sprite move to a specific position by clicking the mouse?

best regards, alex

```
        mCurrentMouseState = Mouse.GetState();

        if (mCurrentMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
            mDestination = new Vector2(mCurrentMouseState.X, mCurrentMouseState.Y);


        Vector2 direction = Vector2.Normalize(mDestination - mPosition);

        mPosition += direction * (float) gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds * mSpeed;

        if (Vector2.Distance(mPosition, mDestination) < 1)
            direction = Vector2.Zero;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code only moves the sprite one pixel once per game tick. If you want to move it instantly just use :

```
if(mCurrentMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
{
      mPositionBat = mCurrentMouseState;
}
```

Comment: thats of course smarter than my code. But my main problem is that i want the sprite go to the MouseState even when I release the button.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do. If you simply want something like I a mouse cursor just use `mPositionBat = mCurrentMouseState;` without any condition. _Also as a side note. If this is the first game you're trying to make I'd advise you against making a strategy game and instead try something easier like Pong or Tetris first._

Comment: mPositionBat = mCurrentMouseState; doesn't work because mPositionBat is a Vector2 and mCurrentMouseState is a MouseState. I am studying right now and my task is to make a sprite move to the point where you click your mouse. When i make mPositionBat.X = mCurrentMouseState.X;, the sprite is not moving slowly to the direction but jumps immediately to the point where i clicked the mouse.

Comment: Then you can use `mCurrentMouseState.Position.ToVector2()`

Comment: I made something different, I edited the Code. Now the sprite moves to the postiton where the mouse clicked, but it starts also with moving even though I haven't pressed any button.